# Generalised version of nearest-neighbour using the kernel trick

Tags: machine-learning, self-study, kernel-trick, k-nearest-neighbour

I am learning about the kernel trick and one of the questions in the textbook is:

`A new input vector v is assigned to the class of the nearest vector v0
by the distance function || v - v0 ||^2. Formulate a generalised version
of the nearest-neighbour classifier using the kernel trick.`

I know about the common kernel functions like gaussian but how would I come up with a new kernel function? Is there any standard procedure when we formulate a new kernel method?

Comment: please add the `self-study` tag

Answer (score -1):

Not sure I understand what "the kernel trick" is fully.

But I guess you need a kernel function at gives the squared distance between v and any vectors in your dataset. If you want it to be the closest then you divide the distance by a very very large number.